# Find intersection of two lines in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I'm using an image processing library (aForge) to process images.  In this case, I'm trying to pick out a playing card from an image.  aForge calculates Hough Lines, for any edges that it detects.  Each Hough Line is produced in a polar coordinate from the center of the image.  Here's an example, along with angle (Theta) and radius (Rad).

I want to extract the card, in order run it through an image recognition to identify suit and rank.

To extract the card, I need to calculate the intersection of the lines, then cut out the rectangular(ish) image.

Here's a sample, the Hough Lines appear in pink, the selected 1st Hough Line appears in bold.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection point $(x,y)$ of two Hough Lines

$$ \begin{aligned}
 x \cos \theta_1 + y \sin \theta_1 &= r_1 \\
 x \cos \theta_2 + y \sin \theta_2 &= r_2 \\
\end{aligned}$$

is given by

$$\begin{aligned}
 x & = \frac{r_2 \sin \theta_1 - r_1 \sin \theta_2}{\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)} \\
 y & = \frac{r_1 \cos \theta_2 - r_2 \cos \theta_1}{\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed, see sample image from my test harness below.

Comment: Not to comment on the stability of the denominator, but if its available to you, a trick to simplify these equations, if you start from the point-slope equations/form, is to let the point of L1 be the origin, making r2 ideally smaller, and at least setting r1 to zero. Then sin/cos of t2 is unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

The Hough line equation is
$$
x\,\cos\theta + y\,\sin\theta = r
$$
see, for example, [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Detecting_lines).

In order to find the intersection, you have to find the solution of the following system of equations:
$$
x\,\cos\theta_1 + y\,\sin\theta_1 = r_1 \\
x\,\cos\theta_2 + y\,\sin\theta_2 = r_2
$$
which can also be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta_1 & \sin\theta_1 \\
\cos \theta_2 & \sin\theta_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1 \\
r_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample implementing John's answer.

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked.